# R draw 2 pie charts with plotly

Tags: r, pie-chart, plotly, data-manipulation

I have a question about drawing pie charts.
Following is my `csv` raw data:

```
type,com,year,month,value
type,com,year,month,value
A,CH,2015,1,0
A,CH,2015,2,0
A,CH,2015,3,0
A,CH,2015,4,0
A,CH,2015,5,0
A,CH,2015,6,0
A,CH,2015,7,0
A,CH,2015,8,2200
A,CH,2015,9,111384
A,CH,2015,10,28758
A,CH,2015,11,21161
A,CH,2015,12,0
A,CH,2016,1,0
A,CH,2016,2,0
A,CH,2016,3,0
A,CH,2016,4,0
A,CH,2016,5,0
A,CH,2016,6,0
A,CH,2016,7,0
A,CH,2016,8,0
A,CH,2016,9,453128
A,CH,2016,10,868256
A,CH,2016,11,1015080
A,CH,2016,12,650912
A,ZU,2015,1,0
A,ZU,2015,2,0
A,ZU,2015,3,0
A,ZU,2015,4,0
A,ZU,2015,5,0
A,ZU,2015,6,61273
A,ZU,2015,7,27711
A,ZU,2015,8,161780
A,ZU,2015,9,48889
A,ZU,2015,10,72805
A,ZU,2015,11,131466
A,ZU,2015,12,73756
A,ZU,2016,1,400
A,ZU,2016,2,0
A,ZU,2016,3,0
A,ZU,2016,4,0
A,ZU,2016,5,0
A,ZU,2016,6,0
A,ZU,2016,7,0
A,ZU,2016,8,10000
A,ZU,2016,9,147533
A,ZU,2016,10,64572
A,ZU,2016,11,57542
A,ZU,2016,12,0
```

I use `group_by()` to group `com` & `year`.

```
by_comyear <- group_by(data, com, year)
sumdataA <- summarise(by_comyear, sum(value))
sumdataA
     com  year `sum(value)`
  <fctr> <int>        <int>
1     CH  2015       163503
2     CH  2016      2987376
3     ZU  2015       577680
4     ZU  2016       280047
```

However, I want to draw 2 pie charts. One for *year 2015*, another for *year 2016*.
How can I draw with package **plotly**: `plot_ly()` function
maybe I should separate `sumdataA` to 2?

very appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear what specifically you want to plot in the pie chart. This is just a basic example with year side by side. You could use:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(COM = c("ch", "ch", "zu","zu"), year = c("2015", "2016","2015", "2016"), values= c(100,125,65,17))
data2015 <- filter(df, year == "2015")
data2016 <- filter(df, year == "2016")

plot_ly(data2015, labels = ~COM, values = ~ values, type = "pie", domain = list(x = c(0, 0.5), y = c(0, 1))) %>%
  add_trace(data = data2016, labels = ~COM, values = ~ values, type = "pie", domain = list(x = c(0.5, 1), y = c(0, 1)))
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: oh, u r so nice. But, actually I just filter a little part of my original data and use it as an example to ask question. There are at least 5 levels in `com`. And my goal is to draw 2 plots. U can ignore `typeB` and only focus on `typeA`. I hope there are 2 pie charts between each other and the left is *2015 typeA*, the right is *2016 typeA*.

Comment: Thus, when using `plotly`, labels should be like this: `labels = ~com`

Comment: Just add COM to you group_by function. To keep it simple you could have one data2016 and data2015. Then use p1 <- plot_ly(data2015...) and p2 <- plot_ly(data2016...). Then use subplot(p1, p2) to have both plots side by side.

Comment: thanks. I edit my data above. U got my point. I just wonder whether i really need to have one data2016 and data2015. Is there other ways? If it really needs to split to 2 data, how to do that? very appreciate

Comment: i try `subplot()`, but it doesn't show plots side by side. it only shows 2016